# Linux Libertine does not show Greek SmallCaps

Tags: fonts, small-caps, greek, libertine

According to the [Linux Libertine font tester](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=86&L=1) you can have Greek small caps.

However the following example does not yield the desirable result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
    \textsc{Small Capitals}
    \textsc{Πεζά κεφαλαία}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Small caps for latin characters but not for Greek ones.]

Comment: Testing the site with cyrillic letters (that surely have *no* small caps), I suspect that the renderer emulates small caps when not available.

Answer (score 5):

this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}% lualatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineOC},% fontname may be different
             SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Small Capitals}
\textsc{Πεζά κεφαλαία}
Πεζά κεφαλαία

\end{document}
```

The font file is available at https://github.com/wilkie/resources/blob/master/fonts/LinLibertine/LinLibertine_C-4.0.4.otf or http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/Fonts/

[image]

Comment: Just got the latest (5.3.0_2012_07_02) Linux Libertine OTF package from Sourceforge. I can't see a `LinLibertineOC` font anywhere. It seems they got rid of the small caps font and added it solely as a `smcp` feature in `LinLibertineO`.

Comment: as I wrote, the name maybe different. Have a look into the definition of the font with `otfinfo -i ...` or look into the generated file `otfl-names.lua`

Comment: Before this version, there was a file dedicated to the Capitals font, and I could see a separate line in `fc-list`. With this new version, it's in the same file as Regular, and it doesn't appear on a separate line in `fc-list`, hence my remark.

Comment: as @Raphink I have the latest package of the fonts and there is no `LinLibertineOC`. However, I replaced this name with all the other available Libertine fonts (e.g. `LibLibertine_R`,`LibLibertine_RZI`), with no luck :( (p.s. in `SmallCapsFont` property do I use the font filename or the font name?)

Comment: You would have to download an older version and install (only) `LinLibertineOC` from it. For some reason Greek small caps are not (yet) supported.

Comment: @Crissov: I added a location for the OTF version.

Comment: @kwstas: See my edited answer