# Arabic comma in polyglossia

Tags: punctuation, polyglossia, arabic

I'm writing a book of probability in arabic, and was using for this arabtex, which is now obsolete for my use. I've done my migration to polyglossia arabic, by the way,

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}
```

I've a problem now. The comma was automatically changed in arabic comma (،) by arabtex, but this is not done by my new packages. How can I obtain this. Precisely, how to obtain the arabic comma (،) in compilation when I write (,) in my .tex file ?
Thank you for reply.

---

I have the reflex to write , instead of ، even when I write arabic text, and a chance is that it is transformed in arabtex in arabic comma... I can replace the character , by the character ،  with the editor (here texmaker)  but not automatically because in mathematics mode (between $) it's not taken in account and, if $f(x,y)$ is replaced by $f(x،y)$ is compiled $f(x y)$, which is clearly a problem...
The mapping what you are talking about must solve this problem, of comma in text, and comma in mathematics.
Thanks

Comment: Well, you can always type your arabic 'comma'. XeTeX is Unicode aware, so no automatic change is needed. Just type '،' where ever needed.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `Mapping` in `fontspec`. See the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17270/substitute-fonts-glyphs-with-glyphs-from-the-same-font/) for how to create a new mapping.

But why do you have non-Arabic commas in an Arabic text anyway? Isn't `U+060C` used normally when typing Arabic, instead of `U+002C`?